# Multiple real inputs and multiple real outputs in a neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, speech-recognition, mfcc, nolearn

How can I train a perceptron where there are multiple input and output nodes and both are real-valued?

I'm doing this because I want to train a neural network to predict the MFCCs  given some data points (from the signal.)

Here is an example data: http://pastebin.com/dtHGUeax
I wont put the data here because the file is "big".

I am using nolearn at the moment, because later I will add more layers for deep learning.

```
net = NeuralNet(
    layers=[('input', layers.InputLayer),
            ('output', layers.DenseLayer),
            ],

    # Layer parameters
    input_shape=(None, 256),
    output_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax,
    output_num_units=13,

    # Optimization
    update=nesterov_momentum,
    update_learning_rate=0.01,
    update_momentum=0.9,

    regression=True,
    max_epochs=500,
    verbose=1
)
```

The error rate I get with this approach is very high.

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the parameters? Try other learning rates, try without the momentum, try changing the epoch count. There are numerous ways for NN learning to go south, and they mostly depend on your data. Try following the hints [from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32683367/2642204).

Comment: I'll try different parameters. In the answer you sent me the output is one node (1 or 0), in my example there are multiple and real values. I guess what I'm asking is if the "design" of the neural network is good.

Comment: Consider also following the link I've posted in that answer.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The neural network is supposed to mimick the coefficient extraction phase, i.e. I get data points on input (256) and on output I get the coefficients (13).

Answer (score 0):

MFCC extraction from power spectrum is non-linear operation, you can not reproduce it with a single layer. If you want to reproduce it with multiple layers you need to consider MFCC algorithm itself.

MFCC extraction might be represented with the following neural network:

- Layer 1 dense matrix of size 256x40 with logarithm nonlinearity
- Layer 2 dense matrix of size 40x13 without nonlinearity (same as linear nonlinearity or identical nonlinearity in Lasagne)

If you reproduce this network with nolearn it will be able to learn it properly, however, logarithm nonlinearity is not implemented yet in Lasagne, so you will have to implement it yourself. Another solution would be to replace logarithm nonlinearity with tanh or with couple of standard non-linear layers.

So to reproduce MFCC you need to have 2 layers with logarithm nonlinearity or 3-4 layers with say softmax nonlinearity and the last layer must be configured linear nonlinearity.

Comment: So until now I had one input layer of 256 nodes and an output layer of 13 nodes with softmax nonlin. because the window size is 256 frames and for each window 13 coefficients are computed and the overlap of the windows is 96.  What you are saying is that I should get 1 window on input, then have one hidden layer of size 256x40 with tanh nonlin, and for output a layer of size 40x13 with linear nonlin? Or, 40 windows on input, one hidden layer of size 256*40 with tanh nonlin, and an ouput layer of size 40x13 of linear nonlin. meaning I train 40 windows at a time. Also,where did the 40 came from?

Comment: It's all about single window. 40 is a common number of mel filters in filterbank, you can get details here: http://www.practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. But I *already* have computed the MFCCs, using scikits.talkbox.features.mfcc, look at the pastebin. That's why I don't have 40 * 13 in my output layer, I have 13 because for a window of 256 data points, 13 coefficients are computed. For every 256 data points, I have 13 coefficients. This is how the dataset would look like: 
data_pt_1, ..., data_pt_256 coef_1_, ..., coef_13. I'm trying to do this so I can just send 256 data points to my neural net. and get coefficients on output.

Comment: I did not say 40 * 13 output dimension either, I wrote dense matrix 40 x 13, 40 is the input dimension, 13 is the output.

Comment: By why keep in mind the number of filters when the MFCCs are already computed?

Comment: I told you how to construct a network to exactly reproduce MFCC pipeline. Such network is theoretically trainable to have zero error. That means that given enough training data your network will be able to create MFCCs exactly as MFCC algorithm did. If you construct some different network, you will not be able to train it to have zero error.

Comment: So the network will have 256 nodes on input, 40 nodes in the hidden layer with logarithmic nonlinearity and an output layer of 13 nodes with no nonlinearity.